# Repatterning image sprites for different color variations

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

Let me simplify it more,

[image]
This seat image is in PNG format with dimensions 150x54 and when I render it on canvas and get its image data then I can easily change its pixels to RGB space using pixel manipulation.Now here I am only changing pixels which are having alpha > 0.So for colors changing its working fine.

Now coming back to main point I want to draw patterns instead of colors on seat,may be lets say I want to draw pattern of flowers, now I want to know how this can be drawn only on non transperent area of seat? I know I can use createPattern function of canvas but it will render on all 150x54 pixels that I dont want.

Any ideas how this can be done?

I am creating bicycle view in HTML5 and I want to customize the bike with different colors.

I have achieved it using HTML canvas along with different images for different parts of cycle.Now client needs to render patterns instead of color, so I need to know how best I can render image patterns instead of color on appropriate part at proper x,y and size.

In color rendering I am using pixel manipulation and changing RGB values of each pixel, but for patterns I dont know how to change the pattern image data with RGB values?

Any idea how this can be done? Or any alternative way?

Comment: Thank you! This is much more clear question now.

Comment: So Any Idea now how to do this?????

Comment: Please do not use excessive question marks as it is a sign for lack of professionalism and may not encourage people to answer for your questions

Answer (score 0):

You can target drawing operations to certain pixels using composite operations.

For example, see

http://mrcoles.com/blog/canvas-composite-operations-demo-animation/

If you choose "source-atop" the balls are only drawn where there are underlying text below.

This way you could target pattern to be drawn only where there is saddle non-alpha pixels below.

I am unsure if createPattern() supports composition. If it doesn't do that then you can manually just repeat drawImage() over all the image.

Comment: The source-atop was the right pointer to start with but still this is not covering actual image data and it is covering transparent images as well , I mean whole square image is getting drawn.Any other idea?